# How can I get the values of SqlDataSource SelectParameters?

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I need to debug some code involving SqlDataSource SelectParameters, and I would like to get the value of these parameters, but so far I'm only able to get the name of the parameters.

```
Dim debug As String = "Parameter 1: " & SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Item(0).ToString() & "<br />" & _
        "Parameter 2: " & SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Item(1).ToString() & "<br />" & _
        "Parameter 3: " & SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Item(2).ToString() & "<br />" & _
        "Parameter 4: " & SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Item(3).ToString() & "<br />" & _
        "Parameter 5: " & SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Item(4).ToString() & "<br />" & _
        "Parameter 6: " & SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Item(5).ToString() & "<br />" & _
        "Parameter 7: " & SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Item(6).ToString() & "<br />" & _
        "Parameter 8: " & SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Item(7).ToString() & "<br />" & _
        "Parameter 9: " & SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Item(8).ToString() & "<br />"

    Label3.Text = debug
```

Output:

```
Parameter 1: institution
Parameter 2: type
Parameter 3: skoleaar
Parameter 4: termin
Parameter 5: fag
Parameter 6: niveau
Parameter 7: tid
Parameter 8: fritekst
Parameter 9: orderby
```

That's the name of the parameters, where I need the values.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you handle the [`Selecting` event of the `SqlDataSourceControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selecting.aspx), the [`Command` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourcecommandeventargs.command.aspx) of the [`SqlDataSourceEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourceselectingeventargs.aspx) parameter will give you the [`DbCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.aspx) which is about to execute. From there, you can use the [`Parameters` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.parameters.aspx) to examine the parameters being passed to the command.

Answer (score 1):

I use a "stub" or debug method, as part of an event call from the 
`asp:SqlDataSource` tag:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsProgram" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ATCNTV1ConnectionString %>" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"
    SelectCommand="<<<my select command for example>>" OnSelecting="dsProgram_Selecting">
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void dsProgram_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (SqlParameter P in e.Command.Parameters)
    {
        //for debugging only
    }   
}
```

Then I debug into the code and watch the 'P' value and all its elements.

Works great. Once I know what's going on, I delete the method and the event call.